# Выдаются странные ошибки при компиляции библиотеки c++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

пишу dll'ку для чита, ничего не подчеркивается, но когда запускаю, выдаются ошибки,что объекты и классы не заданы.

Функция вызываемая в точке входа (main.cpp):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "Classes.h"
#include "stdafx.h"


void no_flash() {
SSystemGlobalEnvironment* pEnv = (SSystemGlobalEnvironment*)(*(DWORD*)(0x18C23DC));
while (true) {
    if (!pEnv)continue;
    I3DEngine* p3DEngine = pEnv->p3DEngine;

    if (!p3DEngine)continue;
    p3DEngine->SetPostEffectParam("Flashbang_Time", 0, true);
}
}
```

Классы:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
class SSystemGlobalEnvironment;
class I3DEngine;

class SSystemGlobalEnvironment
{
public:
I3DEngine* p3DEngine;
char _0x0000[136];
};

class I3DEngine
{
public:

virtual void SetPostEffectParam(const char*pParam, float fValue, bool bForceValue = false);

virtual void Function0(); 
virtual void Function1(); 
virtual void Function2();
...
virtual void Function140(); 
virtual void Function141(); 
virtual void Function142();
};
```

Ошибки в main.dll при компиляции:

```
Error   C2065   'I3DEngine': undeclared identifier
Error   C2065   'p3DEngine': undeclared identifier  
Error   C2065   'p3DEngine': undeclared identifier  
Error   C2065   'p3DEngine': undeclared identifier  
Error   C2065   'pEnv': undeclared identifier   
Error   C2065   'pEnv': undeclared identifier
Error   C2065   'pEnv': undeclared identifier   
Error   C2065   'SSystemGlobalEnvironment': undeclared identifier   
Error   C2059   syntax error: ')'
```

Comment: не подключили хэдэр судя по всему

Comment: Если бы не подключил - подчеркнулись бы названия классов в main'е, но они не выделились. Разве не так ?

Comment: для начала "они бы выделились" - это относится к IDE, а не к компилятору. К тому же нужно подключть верный хэдэр и чтобы в нем было объявление класса.

Comment: Вы что-то выдумываете. Если все так, как вы рассказываете (и да, `#include "stdafx.h"` должен идти первым), то таких ошибок быть не может.

Comment: Поставил stdafx.h на первое место - и правда помогло, спасибо. Но выскачили еще 2 ошибки: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
    Error LNK2005 "void __cdecl no_flash(void)" (?no_flash@@YAXXZ) already defined in dllmain.obj flashdll 
    и  Error LNK1169 one or more multiply defined symbols found flashdll

Comment: Вы привели неполное сообщение об ошибке.  Обычно из полного набора сообщений видно, где еще определена функция.